# php complex query, remove the last occurence string and html maching pattern

Tags: php, html

I have a menu items which gives the output via php to html

```
<ul class="menu"><li class="item5"><a href="/pgsweb/home.html"><span>Home</span></a></li><li><span><a>  | </a></span></li><li class="item25"><a href="/pgsweb/about-us.html"><span>About Us</span></a></li><li><span><a>  | </a></span></li><li class="item26"><a href="/pgsweb/products.html"><span>Products</span></a></li><li><span><a>  | </a></span></li><li class="item27"><a href="/pgsweb/research-a-development.html"><span>Research &amp; Development</span></a></li><li><span><a>  | </a></span></li><li class="item28"><a href="/pgsweb/careers.html"><span>Careers</span></a></li><li><span><a>  | </a></span></li><li class="item29"><a href="/pgsweb/contact-us.html"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li><li><span><a>  | </a></span></li></ul>
```

that's the output and desired output is that it should not print the last "`<li><span><a>  | </a></span></li>`"

and that pipe is coming from the database which means it's dynamic and can be replace by - or anything anytime

plus menu items are also dynamic (added/edited/removed)

```
$this->_buffer .= // code to get the menu name with their link;
```

Following is the php code to display the pipes after every li

```
$this->_buffer .= '<li><span><a> ' . $spacer_start . ' </a></span></li>';
```

I tried to remove that last $this->_buffer by rtrim , but no success ..

please help

Thanks in advance
Dave

Comment: In other words, you want to remove the last li element? Since you seem to have access to the generating code, why dont you just count the amount of menu items and stop appending them to the buffer when the last item is reached?

Comment: On a sidenote, `li span a` sounds completely wrong to me. The spacer isnt an anchor. Semantically, its not even a list item. Use CSS to add those spacers instead.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you prevent the last

```
$this->_buffer .= '<li><span><a> ' . $spacer_start . ' </a></span></li>';
```

?

Otherwise remove it with

```
$this->_buffer = substr($this->_buffer, 0, -$length_of_last_part)
```

or with

```
$this->_buffer = preg_replace('#<li><span><a>  \| </a></span></li>$#', '', $this->_buffer);
```

Comment: Everything is dynamic. that's why it's complex